# How to paste a feature multiple times at once?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, copy

I have a feature class and I want to paste one of the records multiple times. I know this will duplicate the record but that is my intention. I also know that I can simply copy and paste the record and it will duplicate it. I was wondering if there was a way to duplicate the record 10 times at the same time instead of copying and pasting over and over.

Comment: Do you know arcpy ?